# One of my classes cannot find file that I'm passing through it Java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to scan a file with one of my classes but it cannot find the file. The string filename contains the file path. If anyone can help that would be awesome, Thank you!

```
    check.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(file != null){
                String filename = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
                SpellChecker sc = new SpellChecker(filename);
                sc.checker();
                //System.out.println(filename);
            }

        }
    });


public SpellChecker(String filename) 
{

    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));)//go and read the file with the undivided dictionary
    {
        String word="";
        while(in.hasNextLine())//loop through every line
        {
            word=in.nextLine()+" ";// add the words from that line
        }
        wtc = fileSplitter(word);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) // if the file is not found where it is specified to be throw exception.
    {
        System.out.println(E_NOT_FOUND);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you even passing in a String filename when all you really need is the File, something that the FileChooser readily gives you. Other issues: what problems occur with this code? Are you getting error messages or exceptions? Also the code is not very complete -- can you create and post a valid [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please check the links and ask about anything that confuses you). Also, do post any more information that helps us to better understand your problem, and leave out info that doesn't.

Comment: Your while loop reads in lines and then discards them, all except the last.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is this any better? I added more of my code. It's a spell checker that goes through the contents of the file and checks to see if the words are in a dictionary text file. If not, then it prints them out saying they're spelled incorrectly. The program works, I am just trying to make a GUI for it.

Comment: Again, this line `word=in.nextLine()+" ";// add the words from that line` is not doing what you think it's doing. It's discarding the text it gets

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay thanks for noticing that, I will take a look at it. But that's not my problem currently. I want to figure out why it can't find the file.

Comment: No just a program I am trying to make a GUI for

Comment: Ah, it's JavaFX, put in that question tag

Comment: No-one can really tell why it's not finding the file, without knowing what `FIleUtils.readFileToString()` does (it certainly doesn't sound like it gets the path of the file). But as has already been pointed out, you have completely redundant code: you have a `File` object, you convert it to a string, only to convert it back to another `File`. Why not just pass the `File` directly to the `SpellChecker`???

Comment: @James_D my SpellChecker only takes in a string

Comment: Can't you write it so that it takes a `File` too? And if not, can you do `System.out.println(filename);` to see what is actually being passed in?

Comment: @James_D when I print filename, it is the exact path of the file so thats why I don't understand why it won't work